# How to fetch answer from google knowledge panel into a variable in python?

Tags: python, google-search-api

The following code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
search_results=[]
query="who is the father of Tom Cruise"
keyword=query.replace(" ", "+")
google_search = "https://www.google.co.in/search?sclient=psy-ab&client=ubuntu&hs=k5b&channel=fs&biw=1366&bih=648&noj=1&q="+keyword
r=requests.get(google_search)
soup=BeautifulSoup(r.text,"html.parser")
url=soup.findAll('span',{"class":"st"})
for u in url:
    search_results.append(u.text)
    print("u===",u)
    break
```

Gives:

> u=== Cruise was born in Syracuse, New York, the son of Mary Lee (née Pfeiffer), a special education teacher, and **Thomas Cruise Mapother III**, an electrical engineer, both originally from Louisville, Kentucky. He has three sisters: Lee Anne, Marian, and Cass.

But google knowledge panel gives:

> Thomas Mapother III

I need this (Thomas Mapother III), how can I make the python code give me the content of google knowledge panel?

Comment: If you look a the response from the server with for example `print(r.text)` and you use some HTML pretty formater, you will find out, that this knowledge panel is not included in this HTML. I have not found any way to load it there as well. Did you make any progress?